# How to write regular expression for string which contains minimum one number and does not contain any letter?

Tags: c++, regex

How to write regular expression for string which contains minimum one number and does not contain any letter? Position of number or letter is not interesting. Another characters in string are also not interesting.

```
QString str;
if (str.contains(QRegExp("[0-9]")) && !str.contains(QRegExp("[a-zA-Z]")))
...
```

Basically, I need to join theese two conditions in one regular expresion. How to do it?

Comment: What else can be in the string beside numbers?

Comment: There's a saying about regular expressions, going something like this: "I have a problem. I solved it with regular expressions. Now I have *two* problems". Don't overuse or misuse regular expressions. In this case, if you want to see if a string contains only digits you can simply loop over the string and check if each character is a digit. Or you can attempt to convert the string to a number, and the right function will have validation that all of the string was converted (i.e. was all digits).

Comment: Agree. If performance is a reason not to scan the string twice, then a regexp is not the best solution anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with `^[^a-zA-Z]*[0-9]+[^a-zA-Z]*$` (allows any optional non letter char in the string) if you want pure numbers you may just use string start/end `^[0-9]+$`

Comment: @Detonar, no, you are right, it would match that string. I corrected it

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
QString str {...};
if (QRegExp("[^a-zA-Z]*[0-9][^a-zA-Z]*").exactMatch(str))
```

The "[0-9]" is for the digit that must match.

Before and after the digit can be any number of characters except letters ("[^a-zA-Z]*").

If you are not using `exactMatch` but `indexIn` or `contains` then you need to add '^' and '$' for matching the beginning and the end of the string or you need to check if the regexp matches at the beginning and matches the complete string (length).

Comment: This is wrong. this will match for example: a!111. I do not want any letter in the match.

Comment: @PeterPolak Can you please explain? I just checked with: `QString str{ "a!111" };
 const bool b{ QRegExp("[^a-zA-Z]*[0-9][^a-zA-Z]*").exactMatch(str) };` and b was false. What did you test/do? Why do you say it is a wrong match?

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose you can use this regular expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{0}([\W\d]+)[a-zA-Z]{0}$
```

\d matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

\W matches no-word characters

[a-zA-Z]{0} we avoid the characters

+ it means that we want at least one

^ and $: they mean start and end string; in that way we force match of the regular expression for the complete string (from its start to its end)

you can play with this regular expression here
https://regex101.com/r/cXzI1A/2

Comment: This wouldn't match special characters. According the question special characters should match.